# eOS Loki on Chromebook wont start after suspend

Tags: release-loki, suspend, chromebook

I upgraded from Freya to Loki recently on my Chromebook (clean install, no crouton etc.). 
When I try to restart the Chromebook from suspend the display stays dark and needs to be rebooted. On Freya everything worked just fine...

Any advice or suggestions?

Thx

Comment: I have the same issue when I install proprietary drivers for my external video card. Very annoying.

Comment: Which Chromebook are you trying to install this on?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this is about the kernel issues. In some devices (Chromebooks), a newer kernel will solve the problem, but others no.
I guess you are using BOOT_STUB or full rom firmware. Changing it to RW_LEGACY firmware may help.
Here are some links about this problem:

https://m.reddit.com/r/GalliumOS/comments/4ux2qc/suspend_not_working_on_swanky/

https://github.com/GalliumOS/galliumos-distro/issues/268

Comment: Hi, I am using legacy boot on my chromebook...

Answer (score 1):

This is a confirmed bug that located [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1628929). I have found the best way to deal with this bug without rebooting is to switch your TTY (`CTRL`-`ALT`-`F1`) and run `sudo killall lightdm`. It should switch you back to the login screen and you should be able to log in and get back to your desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Although the fact that it stays completely black in your case might suggest you have another issue, I would still take a look at number six [here](http://www.circuidipity.com/c720-ubuntubook.html), which solved my suspend issues:

> Problem: Suspend-and-resume generates a stream of errors ...
>
> ```
> ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: port 1 resume error -19
> ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: port 2 resume error -19
> usb usb3-port1: over-current condition
> usb usb3-port1: connect-debounce failed
> usb usb3-port2: over-current condition
> usb usb3-port2: connect-debounce failed
> ```
>
> ... and blocks the Chromebook from executing a proper restart/shutdown.
>
> FIX: Create `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/ehci-pci.sh ...`
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
>
> case $1/$2 in
>     pre/*)
>     # Unbind ehci for preventing error
>     echo -n "0000:00:1d.0" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci-pci/unbind
>     ;;
>     post/*)
>     # Bind ehci for preventing error
>     echo -n "0000:00:1d.0" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci-pci/bind
>     ;;
> esac
> ```
>
> ... and make it executable ...
>
> ```
> $ sudo chmod 755 /lib/systemd/system-sleep/ehci-pci.sh
> ```
>
> Configure boot options in /etc/default/grub ...
>
> ```
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash tpm_tis.force=1"
> ```
>
> ... save the changes and run ...
>
> ```
> $ sudo update-grub
> ```
>
> Suspend now works reliably when triggered from Ubuntu's shutdown menu or closing the lid and will resume the system with the desktop locked and a password prompt.